# Magento 2: Get discount price after rule applied

Tags: magento2, cart, shopping-cart-price-rules

Magento 2 get the discount price after rule applied. i.e I have different rules applied on cart. how can I find which rule give how much discount on subtotal. Currently, I can find the discount amount of item from the quote. but I want to find a discount amount after only one rule instead of all the rules. I have tried this $item->getDiscountAmount() but this gives the discount price after all rules applied;